# Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 6) are incompatible in CNN

Tags: tensorflow

this is my y_train:

```
array(['smallpox', 'chickenpox', 'cowpox', ..., 'monkeypox', 'smallpox',
       'smallpox'], dtype='<U10')
```

contains 6 different categories and I get the error that my shapes are incorrect in the last layer

The model is Model:

```
  "model_19"
    _________________________________________________________________
     Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
     input_48 (InputLayer)       [(None, 64, 64, 3)]       0         
                                                                     
     conv2d_23 (Conv2D)          (None, 64, 64, 3)         84        
                                                                     
     efficientnetb3 (Functional)  (None, None, None, 1536)  10783535 
                                                                     
     global_average_pooling2d_16  (None, 1536)             0         
      (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                       
                                                                     
     dense_59 (Dense)            (None, 6)                 9222      
                                                                     
    =================================================================
    Total params: 10,792,841
    Trainable params: 10,705,538
    Non-trainable params: 87,303
    _________________________________________________________________
```

The error is:

```
    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 6) are incompatible
```

Comment: Are you labels strings? They need to be mapped to unique integer values starting from 0. Then use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as your loss or one-hot encode your integet labels and use `categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: Why I can't predict categories rise as a string?

Comment: Well, because your loss function works with numbers and you want to update your model's weights based on the loss..You can easily map your predictions back to strings during inference..

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your categories of type string to integers by using pandas.Categorical. For example

i have created a data frame which contained labels using

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels':['apple','mango','orange','apple']})
```

you can convert those to integers pandas.Categorical

```
df['int'] = pd.Categorical(df['labels']).codes
```

output:

```
   labels   int
0   apple   0
1   mango   1
2   orange  2
3   apple   0
```

Then you can pass those integers to train your model. Thank You.